# Getting statistics from different tables in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I have been trying to use this code to count statistics from different tables in my database but I always get wrong numbers

```
SELECT count(`students`.`studentid`)AS 'students',count(`subjects`.`subjectid`)AS 'subjects',count(`grades`.`gradeid`)AS 'grades',count(`departments`.`departmentid`) AS 'departments' FROM `students` JOIN `subjects`,`grades`,`departments`
```

Could any body please tell me what's wrong with my query?

[UPDATE]
Tables Structure

http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/2561/5d5s.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that the actual query you are running? Looks crazy to me, no join conditions

Comment: can you post your complete query statement and possibly the structure of your database tables? The query statement that you have here is definitely not correct in terms of syntax.

Comment: MySQL will run this query but with *almost* random result. No `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: @andrew-buchan I don't need to add join conditions because I need to count all the rows in the table :)

Comment: @Maximus2012 The query above is the complete query and it's correct in terms of syntax (It does not show any errors) but it brings totally wrong data

Comment: @ChristianMark So how can I make it show the correct results?